# How to make each cell of listview like card or box?

Tags: android

I want to make a listView where the each cell is separated by some dp's like a card in cardView and also give some shadow. I want something like this how can I get it ?

[image]

Comment: Please use RecyclerView with CardView.

Comment: Do you want to achieve this view without recyclerview/cardview?

Comment: http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2014/10/recycleview-and-cardview-in-android.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**it is called CardView**

**CardView** is another major element introduced in Material Design. Using CardView you can represent the information in a card manner with a drop shadow (elevation) and corner radius which looks consistent across the platform

**compile this library**

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
```

**than add cardview to your layout like this**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardElevation="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
  // add all your controls here
 </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

for more information [androidhive](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/) or [here](http://www.truiton.com/2015/03/android-cardview-example/) or [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)